# Application Inside Application in IIS

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, entity, entity-framework-5

i have 2 projects and both uses the Entity Framework.

MyProject

MyProject.Admin

now when i depoloy to IIS in the fileSystem

i have the URL

localhost/MyProject -> this project contains all its views,bin etc

and

localhost/MyProject/Admin -> this project contains all its views,bin etc

i converted both of them to the Web Applications.

now if i run MyProject, website works fine.

but if i goto the MyProject/Admin then i am getting the error

Server Error in '/MyProject/Admin' Application.

Constructor on type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory' not found.

but lets say if i have separately like the MyProject

then it is working perfectly fine.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have managed by now.

I think it is picking up the web.config of localhost/MyProject and not localhost/MyProject/Admin

Comment: Look up the `inheritInChildApplications` attribute to see how to prevent this.